# Javascript, insert string into another URL string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not sure how I would go about writing a formula to do this... I need to do:

```
current_url = "http://something.random.com/something/something/upload/something/something_else"
new_url = "http://something.random.com/something/something/upload/{NEWSOMETHING}/something/something_else"
```

Basically I'm always trying to insert another string segment exactly after the `upload/` in the original URL. I've thought about using `position` but I don't have a fixed position because `current_url` won't always be the same length. The only constant is that I know the string needs to be inserted after `upload/`, wherever it may be

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
current_url.replace("upload/","upload/{NEWSOMETHING}/")
```

If your string is var `current_url = "http://something.random.com/something/something/upload/something/c_fit/something_else/c_fit/";` and you want to replace everything in between upload and the last c_fit then `current_url.replace(/\/upload\/.*\/c_fit\//,"/upload/"+"<YOUR_STRING>"+"/c_fit/")` but you just want to replace between upload and the first c_fit then `current_url.replace(/\/upload\/.*?\/c_fit\//,"/upload/"+"<YOUR_STRING>"+"/c_fit/")`

Comment: That's a BRILLIANT idea... It never occurred to me because I was so fixated on not changing upload!

Comment: actually @vcosk, it turns out the code is not always that simplistic. I need to replace "upload/[any text whatever up to]c_fit". Basically, the text between `upload/` and `c_fit` is what's getting replaced, but the text between those is varied in length, characters, and etc. Do you know of a way to do this? Happy to make a second question, Just figured I'd ask in case you had another brilliant idea!

Answer (score 0):

```
var current_url = "http://something.random.com/something/something/upload/something/something_else";

var chunks = current_url.split("/");

var str = [];

var s = chunks.shift();
while(s != "upload"){
    str.push(s);
    s = chunks.shift();
}

var new_url = str.join('/')+"/upload/{new something}/something/something_else";

alert(new_url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could easily split the string on the static text "upload".

```
var current_url = "http://something.random.com/something/something/upload/something/something_else";
    var splitArray = current_url.split("upload");
    var additionalParameter = "What_ever_comes_after_upload"
    var new_url = splitArray[0] + "upload/" + additionalParameter + splitArray[1];

alert(new_url);
```